# How to insert 0 value to a timeseries dataset in Python (or SAS)?

Tags: python, sas

I have a dataset as follows:

```
 device   occupancy          time          co2   humidity     ID
      A       1      2019-03-27 10:17:22  848.0  44.653748    1
      A       1      2019-03-27 10:17:22  848.0  44.653748    2
      B       1      2019-03-27 10:17:22  848.0  41.653748    3
      B       1      2019-03-27 10:17:22  848.0  41.653748    4
      C       1      2019-03-27 08:02:05  685.0  39.968201    5
      D       1      2019-03-27 12:16:53  793.0  35.641235    6
```

As you can see the dataset contains all the records when an occupancy(1) is detected while 0 is not recorded. I need to expand it into a new dataset by every 15 minutes. while the occupancy value should be either 1 or 0.

In SAS I've tried the following. only works after delete the duplicates:

```
 proc timeseries data = df1 ; 
 by ID;
 id time interval= Minute15 accumulate = max;
 var occupancy co2 humidity; 
 run;
```

What I want is for example (every 15 mins):

```
  occupancy         time             co2   ...
    1          25Mar19:07:24         616   ...
    0          25Mar19:07:49         0
    0          25Mar19:08:04         0
    ...        ....
```

In python I also tried (after delete duplicates) :

```
time_first = df1['time'].min()  
time_last = df1['time'].max() 
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
     [pd.date_range(time_first, time_last, freq='H'), 
        df1['device'].unique()], names=['time', 'device'])
print (mux)

want = df1.set_index(['time', 'device']).reindex(mux, 
       fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

but reported an error:

```
 "ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"
```

Can anyone help to solve it through Python(preferably) ?

Comment: It's difficult to test anything with a picture, it would mean typing out your data. If you can provide your data as text, we can paste it into programs to test a solution. Please post your data as text, not images.

Comment: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=etsug&docsetTarget=etsug_timeseries_examples01.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en

Comment: The example illustrates the idea, you need to specify the start, finish and the setmiss=0 options to get it filled in. Give that a try and update your question as needed.

Comment: @Reeza thx for your responding, i've re edited.  I've read the link you shared, but the problem is still there.  0 can't be generated.

Comment: Have you looked at `Proc EXPAND`. Each ID in the sample data has only one time point.  What are the criteria for the expanded domain of the timestamp range covered by an ID ?

Comment: @Reeza thank you. the problem has solved. there are duplicate lines, thats why the error happen.

Comment: @Richard thx ! I've also tried that too. this works great to enlarge the datasets. My problem has solved. I've made duplicate lines after merging dataframes on python..... strange...

Comment: To make this discussion an added value to our knowledge base, could someone please summarise the comments in a practical answer to the question? I will reward you with reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Reeza in the comments, one way to do it is by preparing the data with `proc timeseries` by using the `start=` and `end=` options. An easy way to dynamically get your start/end values is to grab them from the data and store them in macro variables beforehand.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select min(time) format=datetime.
         , max(time) format=datetime.
    into :mintime
       , :maxtime
    from have
    ;
quit;

proc timeseries data=have
                out=want;
    by id;

    id time interval   = minute15. 
            start      = "&mintime."dt 
            end        = "&maxtime."dt 
            accumulate = max 
            setmissing = 0
    ;

    var occupancy co2 humidity;
run;
```

A second way to do it without getting min/max values is by first preparing the data with `proc timeseries` and then running it through `proc expand` to fill in missing values.

Data in a `datalines` format is below.

```
data have;
    format time datetime.;
    infile datalines dlm=',';
    input device$ occupancy time:anydtdtm. co2 humidity id;
    datalines;
A,       1,      2019-03-27 10:17:22,  848.0,  44.653748,    1
A,       1,      2019-03-27 10:17:22,  848.0,  44.653748,    2
B,       1,      2019-03-27 10:17:22,  848.0,  41.653748,    3
B,       1,      2019-03-27 10:17:22,  848.0,  41.653748,    4
C,       1,      2019-03-27 08:02:05,  685.0,  39.968201,    5
D,       1,      2019-03-27 12:16:53,  793.0,  35.641235,    6
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 proc timeseries data = df1 ; 
 by ID;
 id time interval= Minute15 accumulate = max;
 var occupancy co2 humidity; 
 run;
```

Comment: Could you please consider adding explanation for the same